# ES6: "TyperError: X is not a function"

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babeljs, es6-class

I am trying to add a function to a class in my Express/Node server, but I keep getting `TypeError: req.session.user.bills[0].getFormattedDueDate is not a function`. I have other classes whose member functions work, including in the same method that throws this error. I checked the type of the objects in `req.session.user.bills` and it was `object`. The project is built with Webpack and Babel.

If I take all of the properties in `req.session.user.bills[0]` and put them in a new object, then the functions work. The data flow for this object works like this. The name of the main file is `server2.js`.

1. The user logs in by hitting and endpoint in `server2.js`.
2. An object name `userDao` gets the user from the database and returns a `User` object with an array of `Bill`s. Both `UserDao` and `User` are `require`d at the top of `server2.js`.
3. Another endpoint is hit to show the bills. This passes the `User` object to an EJS file. It is here that I try to use the function and it doesn't work.

`server.js`:

```
const User = require('babel-loader!./src/model/user.js');
const UserDao = require('babel-loader!./src/model/userDao.js');
const Bill = require('babel-loader!./src/model/bill.js');

const userDao = new UserDao(pool);
...
app.all('/bills', function(req, res) {
    const temp1 = req.session.user.bills[0].getFormattedDueDate();
    res.render('bills.ejs', {
        URL: config.URL,
        user: req.session.user
    })
});
```

But if I instantiate a new object, it works:

```
app.all('/bills', function(req, res) {
    const temp = new Bill(
        req.session.user.bills[0].id, 
        req.session.user.bills[0].userId, 
        req.session.user.bills[0].periodId, 
        req.session.user.bills[0].accountId, 
        null, 
        req.session.user.bills[0].name, 
        req.session.user.bills[0].amount, 
        req.session.user.bills[0].autoPay, 
        req.session.user.bills[0].weekDay, 
        req.session.user.bills[0].dueDate, 
        req.session.user.bills[0].dueDate2, 
        req.session.user.bills[0].paid
    );
    const temp1 = temp.getFormattedDueDate();
    res.render('bills.ejs', {
        URL: config.URL,
        user: req.session.user
    })
});
```

`userDao.js`:

```
//Lots of other data is put in user...
//Bills
for (let i = 0; i < rows[BILLS_INDEX].length; i++) {
    user.bills.push(new Bill(
        rows[BILLS_INDEX][i].id,
        rows[BILLS_INDEX][i].userId,
        rows[BILLS_INDEX][i].periodId,
        rows[BILLS_INDEX][i].accountId,
        new Tag(rows[BILLS_INDEX][i].tagId, rows[BILLS_INDEX][i].userId, rows[BILLS_INDEX][i].name),
        rows[BILLS_INDEX][i].name,
        rows[BILLS_INDEX][i].amount,
        rows[BILLS_INDEX][i].autoPay === 1,
        rows[BILLS_INDEX][i].weekDay === 1,
        rows[BILLS_INDEX][i].startDate,
        rows[BILLS_INDEX][i].startDate2,
        rows[BILLS_INDEX][i].paid === 1
    ));
}

resolve(user);
```

`user.js`:

```
module.exports = class User {
    constructor(id, firstName, lastName, imageUrl, email, tags, items, budgetItems, piggyBanks, bills) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
        this.email = email;
        this.tags = tags || new Array();
        this.items = items || new Array();
        this.budgetItems = budgetItems || new Array();
        this.piggyBanks = piggyBanks || new Array();
        this.bills = bills || new Array();
    }
}
```

`bill.js`:

```
const moment = require('moment');

module.exports = class Bill {
    constructor(pId, pUserId, pPeriodId, pAccountId, pTag, pName, pAmount, pAutoPay, pWeekDay, pdueDate, pdueDate2, pPaid) {
        this.id = pId;
        this.userId = pUserId,
        this.periodId = pPeriodId,
        this.accountId = pAccountId,
        this.tag = pTag,
        this.name = pName,
        this.amount = pAmount,
        this.autoPay = pAutoPay,
        this.weekDay = pWeekDay,
        this.dueDate = pdueDate,
        this.dueDate2 = pdueDate2,
        this.paid = pPaid
    }

    getFormattedDueDate() {
        return moment(this.dueDate).format('MMM DD, YYYY');
    }

    getFormattedDueDate2() {
        return moment(this.dueDate2).format('MMM DD, YYYY');
    }
}
```

I would expect the method to work, since the methods in `userDao.js` work, but I get the undefined method error.

**EDIT:** I checked `req.session.user.bills[0] instanceof Bill` and it returned false.

Comment: You never call `getFormattedDate`

Comment: How are you putting `req.session.user.bills` in the session? It doesn't appear to be a `Bill` object. Are you using `JSON.stringify` -> `JSON.parse`?

Comment: I do in `server2.js` when I instantiate the variable `temp1`.

Comment: When the user signs in, I set `req.session.user  = user` after retrieving all their information.

Comment: You call `getFormattedDueDate` not `getFormattedDate`

Comment: Have you checked if `req.session.user.bills` actually contains `Bill` objects? As I said, it doesn't seem to. I suspect they've been serialised -> deserialised which means all the functions are stripped.

Comment: That was a typo on the error, sorry. I've edited it to make it correct.

Comment: I forgot to mention I checked the type of req.session.user.bills[i] and it was `object`. The new question wizard messed me up :)

Comment: OK...how did you check the type? Because `typeof` will simply tell you `object` for any object. You can check `bills[0] instanceof Bill` which will tell you if it's a Bill or not.

Comment: Ah, I used `typeof`. I'll check `instanceof`.

Comment: It returned false.

Comment: How do I use the methods without the re-instantiating the hundred of objects in `req.session.user`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you store an object in `session`, it is serialized as JSON. And when you retrieve it, it is parsed again, as a plain object. So any original prototype information is lost in this process. As stated in the documentation of the [express-session module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#reqsession):

> To store or access session data, simply use the request property `req.session`, which is (generally) serialized as JSON by the store [...]

To restore the prototype information, you could do:

```
req.session.user.bills.forEach(bill => Object.setPrototypeOf(bill, Bill.prototype));
```

And then this should work:

```
const temp1 = req.session.user.bills[0].getFormattedDueDate();
```

Alternatively, if you just want to be able to call the method once, you can use `.call`:

```
const temp1 = Bill.prototype.getFormattedDueDate.call(req.session.user.bills[0]);
```